# Get Bind Variables In Oracle JDBC Logging

Tags: java, oracle, java.util.logging

I am trying to debug my Java application that queries an Oracle database.

I have started my application with

```
-Doracle.jdbc.Trace=true  -Djava.util.logging.config.file=c:/tmp/oracledebug.properties
```

Containing

```
handlers = java.util.logging.FileHandler
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = c:/tmp/jdbc.log
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
oracle.jdbc.driver.level = CONFIG
```

However, it outputs the SQL with question marks.

Is it possible to log the values of the bind variables?

Comment: I guess you already tried `oracle.jdbc.level=FINEST`?

Comment: Due to the fact that It is highly significant to hide values for security, frameworks dont show the values.

Comment: @NicolasFilotto I did but it is extremely verbose and it didn't look like the data was there but I couldn't be 100% sure.

Comment: @FreeMan Hibernate can show the values. https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-display-hibernate-sql-parameter-values-log4j/

Comment: try with FINE then

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/diagnose.htm):

> `FINE` Logs the entry and exit to every public method providing a detailed trace of JDBC operations. It produces a fairly high volume of log messages.

Set the system property `-Djava.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format="%1$tc %2$s %3$s%n%4$s: %5$s%6$s%n"` to include the logger name in your output file.

When I set the `oracle.jdbc.driver=FINE` using the above SimpleFormatter pattern I see output like:

```
Wed Nov 02 08:43:06 CDT 2016 oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement setString oracle.jdbc.driver
FINE: XXXXXXXX Public Enter: 1, "some input string"
```

Everything after `Public Enter:` are the arguments to [PreparedStatement.setString(int, String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString-int-java.lang.String-).